# Circumference of an ellipse

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry

### Challenge

Unlike the circumference of a circle (which is as simple as \$2\pi r\$), the [circumference (arc length) of an ellipse is hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Circumference).

Given the semi-major axis \$a\$ and semi-minor axis \$b\$ of an ellipse (see the image below, from Wikipedia), calculate its circumference.

By definition, you can assume \$0 < b \le a\$ for input values. The output value must be within \$10^{-6}\$ relative error from the expected answer for the given test cases.

[image]

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Formulas

Relevant information can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Circumference) and [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse.html). \$C\$ is the value of the circumference; \$e\$ and \$h\$ are helper values. The last two are Ramanujan's approximations, the first of which (the crossed-out one) does not meet the error requirements. The second approximation formula (Equation 5) barely does ([verification](https://tio.run/##ZVBNT8JAEL3vrxhuu5R@bEujHjyZGDlJwDPJNlKLgYJUDsZw0hCElOjB1LMx0ZsHY0g42n@yf6TOthIg7mEyb@a9N7MjBl39/EZ0@xeZXDzXTuXk0SKYHTcw1OsIub2/B041k7PXzEcs44Wc3f18OnLyhJxm4wjj2UmtmQnsusRTGhK1h512hOmtTOZUxitNxt8sTTQjTWT8QUty@mK4aUJVT897yzULW2Um4y9uWdaYkKHoiXB0KUK@tnOUR8HVDbes/BTOy2oIxgKsxhu1rdQBhmKBf2NBzu9hd1muXIJ0yS2tGFPVVQF3ElB8EDxMNwvuQhuhnL6btnx4MwGvhMMFUGoZB/mDNPmzYVDZqCrADUs9vk3wCCGs7/tkAIcw6FCheQyiUQ/djE7os9zXLYWMCt1jrdDMGa2QtWyy1jiFSofoanhNqaMQlhyPMUZIgCSaqwutUm4Noxw0cAKT4jVyPR4jQOEv)) for up to \$a=5b\$ (which is also the upper limit of the test cases, so you can use it for your answer).

$$
\require{enclose} \\
\begin{align}
e &= \sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}} \\
C &= 4aE(e) = 4a\int^{\pi/2}_{0}{\sqrt{1-e^2 \sin^2 \theta} \;d\theta} \tag{1} \\
C &= 2 \pi a \left(1-\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}{\left(\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\right)^2 \frac{e^{2n}}{2n-1}}\right) \tag{2} \\
h &= \frac{(a-b)^2}{(a+b)^2} \\
C &= \pi (a + b) \left( 1 + \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} { \left( \frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n n!} \right)^2 \frac{h^n}{(2n-1)^2} } \right) \tag{3} \\
C &= \pi (a + b) \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} { \binom{1/2}{n}^2 h^n } \tag{4} \\
\enclose{horizontalstrike}{C} &\enclose{horizontalstrike}{\approx \pi \left( 3(a+b) - \sqrt{(3a+b)(a+3b)} \right)} \\
C &\approx \pi (a+b) \left( 1+ \frac{3h}{10 + \sqrt{4-3h}} \right) \tag{5}
\end{align}
$$

### Test cases

All the values for C (circumference) are calculated using Equation 4 with 1000 terms, and presented with 10 significant figures.

```
a     b     C
1     1     6.283185307
1.2   1     6.925791195
1.5   1     7.932719795
2     1     9.688448220
3     1     13.36489322
5     1     21.01004454
20    10    96.88448220
123   45    556.6359936
```

Comment: @Arnauld Yes, it is allowed. Sorry if it wasn't clear. It was a conscious decision which is reflected in the test cases (you can see the maximum ratio is 5).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I noticed the restriction applies to the test cases only after posting my comment.

Comment: I’m waiting for an answer that draws a bigger ellipse and counts the pixels

Comment: Please can I highlight that a number of the proposed solutions use characters that aren't in the 7-bit ASCII character set, so it's not accurate to count their expression in "bytes": it should be characters or codepoints, some of which require several bytes for their composition.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd If you're talking about languages like APL (Dyalog Unicode), you may be interested in [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/when-can-apl-characters-be-counted-as-1-byte-each) meta post, you'll find that they frequently use a special character set and that number of bytes == number of characters

Comment: @Nick, I know, but I omitted mention of the various codepages on which APL implementations still frequently insist in order to spare its fans embarrassment. In my case I got round it by writing a 2741 emulator and embedding translation tables...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5nW3nJhBHL0

Comment: @user In python `lambda a,b,R=range:sum(1for x in R(a<<29)for y in R(b<<29)if x*x/a/a+y*y/b/b<1<(x+1)**2/a/a+(y+1)**2/b/b)>>27` unfortunately I couldn't check that it fit the 10^-6 precision requirement, because it's too slow to actually be executed

Comment: edit: should be `<.5**29<` instead of `<1<` in the middle of the condition

Comment: For Mathematica it makes a difference whether the function is called with `1` (exact integer) or with `1.` (machine-precision number). Are we allowed to convert the test cases to machine-precision before the call, or is this task to be done by the function? E.g. are we allowed to make the first test case `{1., 1.}`?

Comment: @Roman Yes, it's fine.

Comment: @user competing for least serious answer https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/211763/circumference-of-an-ellipse/211859#211859

Comment: @user I'm not exactly counting the pixels, but I am using brute force, so...

Comment: On Oct 17, Stand-up Maths released a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5nW3nJhBHL0) about this.

Comment: Why is there still no precise formula for ellipse circumference?

Comment: @emanresu there is a formula, there is for all the curve if one have the parametric representation f(t) te[a b] it is integral[a b]( |f'| dt)

Answer (score 18):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 20 bytes

```
Perimeter[#~Disk~#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277PyC1KDM3tSS1KFq5ziWzOLtOOVbtf0BRZl6Jgr5Dur5DdbWhno6hXq0OkDaCMUwhDCOojDGUNoXSRgZAhgFYqRFQzsRUr7b2/38A)

-2 bytes from @Roman (see comments)

Comment: It's amusing that even though `EllipticE` and `Ellipsoid` are built-ins, this is still the most economical way to do it.  Also, that's a clever way to get around the first argument being the central coordinates.

Comment: -2 by removing `N@` as allowed in the comments.

Answer (score 15):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>68</s> 67 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b,k=2:k>>9or(1-b*b/a/a)*(k-4+3/k)/k*f(a,b,k+2)+6.28319*a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcxBDoIwEIXhvadwOdMOlJkCERO4yzSm0VSBEDaeviYujGX55f1563u/L7PPOY5PfYWbnpUCpVGuaZqGZQOugglOnaKBVLXWu4QumQjfzgravpaL58FoXrfHvEMEJkY8/VTLwV3hcvWFDmVD3Pw/iae2Q8wf)

An exact infinite series, given sufficiently accurate values of \$2\pi \approx 6.28319\$ and \$\infty \approx 9\$.

#### <s>69</s> 68 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b,k=0:k//7*.785398*a*(8-k)or f(a+b,2*(a*b)**.5,k*b/a/2+4)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XczLCsIwEIXhvU/R5cx0mmtDo9CHmSBBibaldOPTx52YLj/@w9k@x2NdfK15fsk73aUTTlxmcytaT6SmGPw1khDEoeC6dxmkT@wIhBISqcCFkhbt@hHrtj@XAzJYtoiXn5Q7OTRuq290Whq25v/JeR4DYv0C)

Another exact series, given sufficiently accurate values of \$\frac\pi4 \approx .785398\$ and \$8 \approx 7\$.  This one converges extremely quickly, using just five recursive calls for each test case!  The recursion exactly preserves the invariant value

$$\left(1 + \frac{kb}{8a}\right)C(a, b) - \frac{kb}{8a}C(a + b, 2\sqrt{a b}),$$

which can then be approximated as \$(1 - \frac k8)2\pi a\$ when \$a, b\$ become sufficiently close.

Comment: Nice solution! For the first one, it looks like `k>>9or` keeps enough precision.

Comment: @xnor Indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>60</s> 57 bytes

```r
function(a,b,c=a+b,h=3*(a-b)^2/c)pi*(c+h/(10+(4-h/c)^.5))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc7NjoIwEMDxu09h4qWVWjsznX4ceBUNNCWQIBp2fX7WJV4kAXuaNPnN/McpdWN63po85iHl67255r7vHj@5nJrnkH67@yAqVatUVkWt2pKOojrV8oLnJB/dUaSiPQswhbCn9vV10Szl6k4Bav//QO4P8@A0BoLAZPxuHWlUnygi@wgQeQvxB/I6EnqIfgvhIi9qF4K1AdGsI1ogIE3Ohtc5XEe8QAjagDHWst3IM7MC81bR6e95gHOg5TdidtoRx0huN01/)

Straightforward implementation of Ramanujan's 2nd approximation (eq 5).

Rather sadly, this approximation comes out as <s>much</s> more concise than a more-interesting **different approach** prompted by the comments: 'draw' a big ellipse, and measure around the edge of it (unfortunately counting the actual pixels wasn't going to work...):

**[R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>90</s> <s>65</s> 62 bytes**

*Edit: -3 bytes by calculating hypotenuse length using `abs` value of complex number*

```r
function(a,b,n=1e5)sum(4*abs(diff(b*(1-(0:n/n)^2)^.5)+1i*a/n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc/dboMgFAfw@z7FSXqjnWWAoLKkr9JG2aGSKG4IS/b0jpomy5rUccPn75w/ftHW6zga9Og0XiZzwWGwHzOeFhOdDnZyWVt0hTsxlPkcx0wc2m7O3q0xWXfI2DGjb@7V5Ween4nMX5g9tGmbL3twU0DQfeuuCA7CBL299ujhqx0izmAmDx2GkE5araNv9Td0McAwJeDBR3cMdsTdHlJrsDPM0RirLbpwKzYiprnHX@zxM1qP4@3BZNa71H0YMNXb7Z59NGMF3AbLYb8uKsKbkjWypPUGIrz4ixSXtWJMyS0k/6CaqJLXTNVbiD/EU6RqGiEazulzVD4gVpKyEk1qx58j@YA4I5RRKoQUG/Hoqhi9K1WR/@MxvgYU8o6krEhVSqXKarcsPw)

**How?** (ungolfed code):

```r
circumference_of_ellipse=
function(a,b                # a,b = axes of ellipse
n=1e6){                     # n = number of pixels to 'draw' across 'a' axis
x=a*0:n/n                   # x coordinates = n pixels from 0 to a
y=b*(1-(x/a)^2)^.5)         # y coordinates = to satisfy (x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 =1
                            # we could actually draw the (quarter) ellipse here
                            # with 'plot(x,y)'
step_y=diff(y)              # step_y = change in y for each step of x
step_x=a/n                  # step_x = size of each step of x
h=(step_y^2+step_x^2)^.5    # h=hypotenuse of triangle formed by step_y & step_x
sum(4*h)                    # sum all the hypotenuses and multiply by 4
                            # (since we only 'drew' a quarter of the ellipse)
```

Comment: Can you please explain the "drawing" algorithm?

Comment: @Stef done - I hope you approve!

Comment: Awesome! I thought this would require a Bresenham-like algorithm but this approach is even better.

Answer (score 8):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>28</s> <s>25</s> 23 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

Thanks to [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler) for -5 bytes!

Assumes `⎕IO←0`.

```apl
f←○1⊥+×9(×⍨*×.5!⍨⊢)∘⍳⍨-÷+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXI9656YBGY@mdxs@6lqqfXi6kdaj3hUaeqaKQOpR72ZLzcPTLbUedcwAsoEiuoe3a@PSA1atAWIeng7V37VYE6TjP6pyS43D04GyWghlizRRbAC5TwGoRcFQIU3BkAvO0zNC45ui8FFljVF4aCoNQFwDhElGINUmpv8B)

This calculates

$$
\pi \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{8} (a+b) \cdot \left( h^{\prime n} \binom{1/2}{n} \right) ^2 \qquad h^\prime =  {{a-b}\over{a+b}}
$$

which is a good enough approximation using the 4th formula.
For the explanation the function will be split into two. `f` is the main function and `g` calculates \$  \left( \alpha^{\prime n} \binom{1/2}{n} \right) ^2 \$ for \$n\$ from \$0\$ to \$\omega-1\$:

```apl
g ← (×⍨*×.5!⍨⊢)∘⍳
f ← ○1⊥+×9g⍨-÷+
```

Starting with `a f b` from the right:

`-÷+` calculates \$h^\prime = (a-b)÷(a+b)\$.
`g⍨` is `g` commuted => `9 g⍨ h' ≡ h' g 9`. `g` returns a vector of the 9 values of \$\left( h^{\prime n} \binom{1/2}{n} \right) ^2\$.
`+×` multiplies \$a + b\$ to this vector.
`1⊥` converts the resulting vector from base 1, which is the same as summing the vector.
`○` multiplies the resulting number by \$\pi\$.

Now to `h' g 9`:

`⍳` is an index generator, with `⎕IO←0`, `⍳9` results in the vector `0 1 ... 8`.
The remaining train `×⍨*×.5!⍨⊢` is now called with \$h^\prime\$ as a left argument and the vector \$v = (0,1, \cdots, 8)\$ as a right argument:

`.5!⍨⊢` is the commuted binomial coefficient called with the vector `v` on its right and \$0.5\$ on its left. This calculates \$\binom{1/2}{n}\$ for all \$n \in v\$.
`*×` multiplies this vector element-wise with \$h^\prime * n\$ (\$*\$ denotes exponentiation).
`×⍨` is commuted multiplication, which given only a right argument, seems to use this as left and right argument? and squares the vector element-wise.

Comment: Turns out using `⍳9` instead of `⍳99` is precise enough, and inlining `x` and using `1⊥` instead of `+⌿∘` gives [25 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/9OA5KPp3YaPupZqH55upPWod4WGnqkikHrUu9lS8/B0S61HHTOAbKCI7uHt2iCtCkA9CoYKaQqGXHCenhEa3xSFjyprjMJDU2kA4hogTDICqTYx/Q8A).

Comment: [23 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXI9656YBGY@mdxs@6lqqfXi6kdaj3hUaeqaKQOpR72ZLzcPTLbUedcwAsoEiuoe3a@PSA1atAWIeng7V37VYE6TjP6pyS43D04GyWghlizRRbAC5TwGoRcFQIU3BkAvO0zNC45ui8FFljVF4aCoNQFwDhElGINUmpv8B). Looks like 22 is possible...

Comment: @Thanks again. This is going to take me some time to understand ;).

Answer (score 7):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 63 bytes

```ruby
->a,b,h=1r*(a-b)/a+=b{3.141593*a*((154+53*h*=h)*h*h/1e4+h/4+1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VdC7boQwEAXQPl8xIg1Pw/iFXZAfQRQ2AnmjlRLxiBSxfDsxsGiVZop7Zm4xw2x/t77asg@T2tRVOMShyWyUm6SyCyPIUWgWmzgMUfBEsNjFlYv8dDl2PHE5TzBat/oNoMYUAPYhCVUMlWBF2aSHEJo@RVNRakQtLhGnlEQzWqIuL6FXmyZSKc4VpcUp7BJkhEmu/CE9RVxCkRRYFJwL/mwr9n0/tCT/25D6Pu4vhZBEMqE1k14a0pnWwQKP/TPtA77naYTAQAXvi1nTgNw/53EKdQQJBPaI7StWR9wf8Vj1tS9pXkr5wUN3N9Ptp4NuGL6GYzcc8zbDiBg7rgGs2x8)

A [direct port](https://tio.run/##VdC7asQwEAXQPl8xOI38kvW2tOD0KQLpzRaSsXHCQoIfgeD1tztaec2SZop7Zm4xw@x@t67a8hebueXNTv3p9P6aINRXfEiQzV2cJKywaeXiAlGSIpH3hfUhwTJObbxu9RNATTMAuA2FmeZUS07KcxYEs@wuhsnSUGrkIXKXEhvOSmrKQ9jRZrDSWgjNGNmFH0I55kpof8h2kYcwigklRAgp7m3ktu@HUfh/G2W@T/hLKRVWXBrDlZczbm3TwwJX/5SsucL3PI0QWajgebFrFuHL5zxOyMSQQuRC7B6xDnEX4rHqal9yfigTgYf2YqePnxbaYfgawi4aiyanMbZuXCNYtz8) of @Arnauld's [JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211770/92901) is shorter (58 bytes). However, I like the 63-byter above because it differs from other approaches in that it's a cubic polynomial: no square roots, no infinite series.

[This excellent review](http://www.ebyte.it/library/docs/math05a/EllipsePerimeterApprox05.html) lists nearly 40 different methods for approximating the circumference of an ellipse, with graphs of the relative error in each approximation as a function of \$b/a\$. Inspection of the graphs shows that only a few of the listed methods are capable of satisfying the required tolerance of \$10^{-6}\$ for all test cases. Since several answers here had already explored 'Ramanujan II' (eq. (5)), I decided to look at the Padé approximations 'Padé 3/2' and 'Padé 3/3'.

A [Padé approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) is a rational function with coefficients chosen so as to match the largest possible number of terms in a known power series. In this case, the relevant power series is the infinite sum that appears in eq. (4). The Padé 3/2 and Padé 3/3 approximants for this series are mathematically straightforward (see the review linked above) but not suited to code golf. Instead, an *approximation to the approximants* is obtained by least-squares fitting. The resulting cubic polynomial (with truncated coefficients), as implemented in the code, is
$$
0.0053h^3 + 0.0154h^2+0.25h+1.
$$
Note that this function is overfitted to the test cases, partly because of the truncation and partly because the fit was optimised using only those values of \$h=(a-b)^2/(a+b)^2\$ that occur in the test cases. (Consequently, `Math::PI` cannot be substituted in place of `3.141593`, despite having the same byte count, without yielding relative errors above the \$10^{-6}\$ threshold for the two test cases for which \$b/a=1/2\$.)

Answer (score 7):

## x87 machine code, <del>65</del> <del>59</del> 53 bytes

```
00000000: d9c1 d9c1 dec1 d9ca dee9 d8c8 d9c1 d8c8  ................
00000010: def9 6a03 8bf4 de0c ff04 df04 d9c1 dee9  ..j.............
00000020: d9fa 8304 06de 04de f9d9 e8de c1d9 ebde  ................
00000030: c9de c95e c3                             ...^.
```

Listing:

```
D9 C1       FLD   ST(1)             ; load a to ST
D9 C1       FLD   ST(1)             ; load b to ST
DE C1       FADD                    ; a + b
D9 CA       FXCH  ST(2)             ; save result for end 
DE E9       FSUB                    ; a - b 
D8 C8       FMUL  ST(0), ST(0)      ; ST ^ 2 
D9 C1       FLD   ST(1)             ; copy a + b result to ST 
D8 C8       FMUL  ST(0), ST(0)      ; ST ^ 2 
DE F9       FDIV                    ; calculate h 
6A 03       PUSH  3                 ; load const 3 
8B F4       MOV   SI, SP            ; SI to top of CPU stack
DE 0C       FIMUL WORD PTR[SI]      ; ST = h * 3 
FF 04       INC   WORD PTR[SI]      ; 4 = 3 + 1 
DF 04       FILD  WORD PTR[SI]      ; load const 4 
D9 C1       FLD   ST(1)             ; load 3h to ST
DE E9       FSUB                    ; 4 - 3h 
D9 FA       FSQRT                   ; sqrt(ST) 
83 04 06    ADD   WORD PTR[SI], 6   ; 10 = 4 + 6 
DE 04       FIADD WORD PTR[SI]      ; ST + 10 
DE F9       FDIV                    ; 3h / ST 
D9 E8       FLD1                    ; load const 1 
DE C1       FADD                    ; ST + 1 
D9 EB       FLDPI                   ; load PI 
DE C9       FMUL                    ; * PI 
DE C9       FMUL                    ; * ( a + b ) from earlier 
5E          POP   SI                ; restore CPU stack 
C3          RET                     ; return to caller
```

Callable function, input `a` and `b` in `ST(0)` and `ST(1)`.  Output in `ST(0)`.  Implements Ramanujan's 2nd approximation (eq 5) in full hardware 80-bit extended precision.

Test program:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES7),  <s>59</s>  56 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @DominicvanEssen*

```javascript
a=>b=>Math.PI*((h=3*(a-b)**2/(a+=b))/(10+(4-h/a)**.5)+a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc1NTsNADIbhPafI0pMonrE9np/FdM8CiStMSkuKqgbRiuuHIJCIUrHxwnr0vW/1s173H6f3W3@ZXg7zscy17Iaye6q3EZ8fW4CxSAu1H0zbsoXalcEYC@Q68P1o6/JGNV018366XKfzAc/TKxyBmsYsx5jG2iYgJ6Gk4uLDhiGvWWaNmSjrHdM/FjELR8rxjvE6mjGk5H1idhsma0aCEnxaJnnDdM2Y0JFz3qvfRt03c7/RgP9EicWA1x@mGjCI5ixh/gI)

Comment: [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##dc1NbsIwEIbhfU@Rpe0oE8@Mxz8Ls@8CqVdwUmioEKkAcf00CKRGQd2MZvHoe7/LrVz68@Hn2pzGz920z1PJmy5vtuU6wMe7UarPpe50rYbMRpWm08ZQ2@tWoa2Va4b5NwZE66kfT5fxuIPj@KX2CqtKz0frqm0rDxQZo7ANbysGtGSJJCTEJC9M/liAxBQwhRdGy2gCH6NzkciuGC8ZMrB3cZ6kFZMlIwSL1jonbh21d2afUQ//RJFYKycPJuLBs6TEfvoF) with a bit of rearrangement

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Thank you! -1 by rearranging a bit more.

Comment: Nice.  Very frustrating that R doesn't have ```+=```...

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>97</s> <s>92</s></sup> 91 bytes

Saved <s>4</s> 5 bytes thanks to [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen)!!!
Saved 2 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!

```c
float f(a,b,k)float a,b,k;{k=k?:2;k=k>999?1:(1-b*b/a/a)*(k-4+3/k)/k*f(a,b,k+2)+6.283185*a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZLbjpswEIbv8xSjSJE4GINtbPCyh4uqT9FEK0NMi0ghAi6iRnn2dDhksxu1CGyP/f3j32OK4GdRXK/loTUDlI4hOandOZrG2bl@qd@eeIbdq9b6jT05LMi9PDShcT2nDmJfhLUb1t6i9rnrK8pTwVLpmexyrZoBfpuqcdzVeQX4zOkH2w/v5scOXuDMCDDKx0YSwF4QGAcRznBxyR5V@V318KIill8E9nS0xWD3s@RmTEQJAUU1l4lmTONmCdWCJ0wnY6CpStM4TvlkQVCh4hSX0RlnNGJRFMcyRkzROyalokpIrYX6auDYV4e2wd1ZZAM1LxW/TOdBN5tab0/f@fakv@En1wQ@x2KNyeZsbQfOWMuq2dsT6qJsGT5DX/2xbenczuqGy4T3MZOB70@0C/Ml3A0azLVcxkTssgcgvwH5fwCLwEed/430iEw/iPu4sreHYbRQmrx3@sB@AsbTFm3XYWIEZvD5VtA7duwQLJ31piSwKSF4HdtNv22wloZATqAnWOsl027Z4LK6XP8C)

Port of [Anders Kaseorg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39242/anders-kaseorg)'s [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211780/9481).

Comment: It could be [93 bytes](https://tio.run/##dZLbbqMwEIbv8xTTSJE4GINtTi5Ne1H1KTbRyhDTImchAi6ijfLs6XBI00a7CIwP3z/ze@zCey@Ky6XcN6qH0lIkJ8aeRmM/O5n1g3nhjyYza/MspXxhjxbzcif3la9sxzJe6Arf2L5xZr3LbTemPBUsjRyVnS9V3cMfVdWWvTgtAJ8pQa@7/rf6tYU1nBgBRvnQRATwLwgMnQBnuDhn96r8prp7URFGPwT6eNBFr3eT5GpMBAmBmEoeJZIxickSKgVPmEyGgaRxmoZhykcLgoo4THEZnXFGAxYEYRiFiMX0hkVRTGMRSSninwYOXbVvaszOAu3F01LxoVoH2snUcnN845ujfMUvWhL4PhZLDDZFa1qwhlpW9U4fURdkc/cJuuqvbkrrulfbnyecr5kMXHekbZgO4WZQYaz5MEZim90B@RXI/wNoBL7q/G@kQ2S8IPb9yk7v@8FCqfLO6jz9DRh2WzRti4ERmMCna0Fv2KFFsLSWq5LAqgTveWhX3abGWioCOYGOYK3nSNs5wXlxvnwC) as recursive function

Comment: ...but I don't know if it's safe to assume that a non-specified function argument always initializes to zero (it seems to do so on TIO...)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen GCC is initializing \$k\$ to zero for each invocation of \$f\$ in the same program run so I believe we're ok - thanks! :D

Comment: I think ceilingcat actually meant ```k?:2``` and not ```k?k:2```, so -2 bytes to 91 bytes...  a new trick for me!

Comment: @Dominic It is indeed `k?:2` which is new to me too. Credited both of you for that byte - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>31</s> 30 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Jonah!

```
[:o.1#.+*i.@9*:@(^~*0.5!~[)-%+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc6xCsJAEATQPl8xicjlLmbZu@TALAgBwcrKNmATDGqTP8ivn2cfthimeDDMN1VkFlwEBicwJKclXB/3W5pkJX@gxn1oHJyM9XNzTLHcJtsem2QLFK/5vcIwDQbnUgJqD2ABvM29oxRUjYoGdblTNaoa@K@e7e6p0GXsY8b0Aw)

Essentially a J port of [@ovs's APL solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211775/75681).

Comment: quick 1 byte savings: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc6xCsJAEATQPl8xicjlLmbZu@TALAgBwcrKNmATDGqTP8ivn2cfthimeDDMN1VkFlwEBicwJKclXB/3W5pkJX@gxn1oHJyM9XNzTLHcJtsem2QLFK/5vcIwDQbnUgJqD2ABvM29oxRUjYoGdblTNaoa@K@e7e6p0GXsY8b0Aw "J – Try It Online")

Comment: @Jonah Ah, so obvious now! Thanks!

Comment: @Jonah or alternatively [[:o.1#.+*i.@9(2^~^~*0.5!~[)-%+](https://tio.run/##fc6xCsJAEATQPl8xicjlErPsbXJgDgRBsLKyDaQJBrXJH9yvn2cfthimeDDMN1VkVlwCDE5ghJyOcHs@7mkKG7kDtc2HrmMtc5xjw@TLONnu2CZboHgt7w2GaTQ4l0FQOwAr4GzuHSVR1Ssq6nKvqldV@K@O7e4p6TMOPmP6AQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 20 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
-ëΣ_¬/²3*_4,√♂+/)π**
```

Port of [my 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211776/52210), and thus also implements a modification of the fifth formula.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/1/38Opzi@MPrdE/tMlYK95E51HHrEczm7T1Nc83aGn9/2@oZ6AAxFyGekZQ2hRMG0HFjaG0KZQ2MgAxDEAqjUByJkAJAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
-                     # b-a
 ëΣ                   # a+b
   _                  # Duplicate
    ¬                 # Rotate stack: b-a,a+b,a+b → a+b,b-a,a+b
     /                # Divide
      ²               # Square
       3*             # Multiply by 3
         _            # Duplicate
          4,          # Subtract from 4
            √         # Square-root
             ♂+       # Add 10
               /      # Divide
                )     # Increment by 1
                 π*   # Multiply by PI
                   *  # Multiply by the a+b we've duplicated
                      # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```
4EllipticE[1-(#2/#)^2]#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b738Q1JyezAMhzjTbU1VA20lfWjDOKVVb7H1CUmVcSraxrl@bg4BetHBurpqDvoFBdbahjWKtTbahnBKVNwTSEZwwmoSIGOoYGIBVGxjomprW1//8DAA)

-1 thanks to @AndersKaseorg

Note that Mathematica uses a different convention for elliptic integrals, hence the square root disappears.

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 73 bytes

```
e a b=(a+b)*pi*(1+3*l/(10+sqrt(4-3*l))+3*l^5/2^17)where l=((a-b)/(a+b))^2
```

Experimenting with an improved version of (5):

$$E(a,b) = \pi (a+b) \left( 1 + \frac{3h^2}{10 + \sqrt{4-3h^2}} + \frac{3h^{10}}{2^{17}}\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 19 bytes

```
y/U_Q.5t_hlbZh*YPE*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v1I/ND5Qz7QkPsMwKSpDKzLAVev/fyMuQwA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8L9SPzQ@UM@0JD7DMCkqQysywFXrv0vIf0MuINQzApOmQBLEMgZiMNuAyxCIjIy5TEwB).

#### Formula used

This is based on formula (1) from the challenge description,
\[
C =  4a\int^{\pi/2}_{0}{\sqrt{1-e^2 \sin^2 \theta} ;d\theta} = 4 a\,E(e),
\]
where \$e\$ is the eccentricity,
\[
e = \sqrt{1 - b^2/a^2},
\]
and \$E\$ is the [complete elliptic integral of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind). This integral can be expressed in terms of [Gauss' hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function), \${}_2F_1\$, as follows:
\[
E(e) = \tfrac{\pi}{2}  \;{}_2F_1 \left(\tfrac12, -\tfrac12; 1; e^2 \right).
\]
Combining the above gives the formula used in the code:
\[
C = 2\pi a \;{}_2F_1 \left(\tfrac12, -\tfrac12; 1; 1 - b^2/a^2 \right).
\]

#### Code explanation

```
y       % Implicit inputs: a, b. Duplicate from below
        % STACK: a, b, a
/       % Divide
        % STACK: a, b/a
U_Q     % Square, negate, add 1
        % STACK: a, 1-(b/a)^2
.5t_h   % Push 0.5, duplicate, negate, concatenate
        % STACK: a, 1-(b/a)^2, [0.5, -0.5]
1       % Push 1
        % STACK: a, 1-(b/a)^2, [0.5, -0.5], 1
b       % Bubble up in the stack
        % STACK: a, [0.5, -0.5], 1, 1-(b/a)^2
Zh      % Hypergeometric function, 2F1
        % STACK: a, 2F1([0.5, -0.5], 1, 1-(b/a)^2)
*       % Multiply
        % STACK: a * 2F1([0.5, -0.5], 1, 1-(b/a)^2)
YPE     % Push pi, multiply by 2
        % STACK: a * 2F1([0.5, -0.5], 1, 1-(b/a)^2), 2*pi
*       % Multiply. Implicit display
        % STACK: 2*pi*a * 2F1([0.5, -0.5], 1, 1-(b/a)^2)
```

Answer (score 3):

## APL(NARS), 21 chars

```
a←⎕⋄{√+/×⍨a×1 2○⍵}∫○2
```

test:

```
      a←⎕⋄{√+/×⍨a×1 2○⍵}∫○2
⎕:
      1 1
6.283185307 
      a←⎕⋄{√+/×⍨a×1 2○⍵}∫○2
⎕:
      123 45
556.6359936
```

it is based on the parametric representation of ellipse something as

`phi(t)=(a cos(t),b sin(t)) t∊[0,2π)`
and the formula for find the lenght of the curve $$L(\varphi)=\int_0^{2\pi} \left| \varphi'(t) \right|dt $$

where `phi'(t)=(a -sin(t), b cos(t) ) t∊[0,2π)`.

It is possible calculate more digit in that integral but solution is more long, as in

```
      ⎕FPC←3000⋄a←⎕⋄300⍕{√+/×⍨a×1 2○⍵}∫○2v
⎕:
      1 1
 6.283185307179586476925286766559005768394338798750211641949889184615632812572417997256069650684234135964296173026564613
      294187689219101164463450718816256962234900568205403877042211119289245897909860763928857621951331866892256951296467
      573566330542403818291297133846920697220908653296426787214520498282547
      300⍕○2v
 6.283185307179586476925286766559005768394338798750211641949889184615632812572417997256069650684234135964296173026564613
      294187689219101164463450718816256962234900568205403877042211119289245897909860763928857621951331866892256951296467
      573566330542403818291297133846920697220908653296426787214520498282547
```

Answer (score 2):

## [SageMath](https://sagemath.org), 37 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:4*a*elliptic_ec(1-b*b/a/a)
```

[Try it online!](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJw1jUEKgzAURPeB3OHvzA8xmlQ3QnuRtpSfVCGgVmx24t0b23Q278EMzHC-cTbS5J4EpFzXSJL9OIYlBv_ovTClk66iipAzzobXCp7ePYQZrsJoZTSqRPuX9ic2N6fMNtPWServ1KauaTXeO84gZVnDHEWx7VBeYNsLnb4miuK4UzAIeQgifgCCUywB&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Uses the elliptic integral formulation.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>22</s> <s>21</s> 20 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÆnIOn/3*D4s-tT+/>IOžqP
```

Implements the fifth formula. Input as a pair \$[a,b]\$.

-1 byte thanks to *@ovs*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cFuep3@evrGWi0mxbkmItr6dp//RfYUB//9Hm@oYxgIA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/w22V/vp5xlouJsW6JSHa@naV/kf3FQb81/kfHW2oYxirE22oZwSlTcE0hGcMJqEiBjqGBiAVRsY6JqaxsQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Æ                     # Reduce the (implicit) input-pair by subtraction: a-b
 IO                   # Push the input-pair again and sum it: a+b
   /                  # Divide them by one another: (a-b)/(a+b)
    n                 # Square it: ((a-b)/(a+b))²
     3*               # Multiply it by 3: ((a-b)/(a+b))²*3
       D              # Duplicate that
        4α            # Take the absolute difference with 4: |((a-b)/(a+b))²*3-4|
          t           # Take the square-root of that: sqrt(|((a-b)/(a+b))²*3-4|)
           T+         # Add 10: sqrt(|((a-b)/(a+b))²*3-4|)+10
             /        # Divide the duplicate by this:
                      #  (a-b)²/(a+b)²*3/(sqrt(|((a-b)/(a+b))²*3-4|)+10)
              >       # Increase it by 1:
                      #  (a-b)²/(a+b)²*3/(sqrt(|((a-b)/(a+b))²*3-4|)+10)+1
               IO     # Push the input-sum again: a+b
                 žq   # Push PI: 3.141592653589793
                   P  # Take the product of the three values on the stack:
                      #  ((a-b)²/(a+b)²*3/(sqrt(|((a-b)/(a+b))²*3-4|)+10)+1)*(a+b)*π
                      # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Note that I use \$\left|3h-4\right|\$ instead of \$4-3h\$ in my formula to save a byte, but given the constraints \$0<b\leq a\$, \$h\$ will be: \$0\leq h<1\$, and thus \$3h\$ will be at most \$2.999\dots\$.
I also use \$h=\left(\frac{a-b}{a+b}\right)^2\$ instead of \$h=\frac{(a-b)^2}{(a+b)^2}\$ to save another byte (thanks to *@ovs*).

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <sup><s>28</s></sup> 26 bytes

```apl
○+×1+∘(⊢÷10+∘√4-⊢)3×2*⍨-÷+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//9H0bu3D0w21H3XM0HjUtejwdkMDEPtRxywTXSBf0/jwdCOtR70rdA9v1/6f9qhtwqPevkddzY961zzq3XJovfGjtomP@qYGBzkDyRAPz@D/hgppCoZchnpGUNoURAMA)

ovs's conversion to a train.

-2 using `√`.

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 35 bytes

```apl
{h←3×2*⍨⍺(-÷+)⍵⋄(○⍺+⍵)×1+h÷10+√4-h}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/vzrjUdsE48PTjbQe9a541LtLQ/fwdm3NR71bH3W3aDya3g0U0gbyNA9PN9TOOLzd0ED7UccsE92M2v9pQI2PevsedTU/6l3zqHfLofXGj9omPuqbGhzkDCRDPDyD/xsqpCkYchnqGUFpUzAN5gEA)

Uses Equation 4.

Longer than the other APL answer because there's more than one usage of \$h\$.

Comment: I got 28 bytes as a train: https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//9H0bu3D0w21H3XM0HjUtejwdkMDbT1TrUe9K0x0gXxN48PTjUA83cPbtf@nPWqb8Ki371FX86PeNY96txxab/yobeKjvqnBQc5AMsTDM/i/oUKagiGXoZ4RlDYF02AeAA

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 52 bytes

```
≧×χφＮθＮηＩ×⁴ΣＥＥφＥ²∕⁺ιλφ₂⁺××θθ⁻Σι⊗₂Πι××ηη⁻⁻²Σι⊗₂⁻⊕ΠιΣι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZC/bsIwEMbn5ilutCVXalA3pqosDFQIeAETX/BJiU2cmAHEs7t2nLZR1OWsz9/97l@lpausbELYyetH39PFHOiiB3aiFnsB5ZuAmq@Lrbn64cu3Z3SsW2gddUZZzL5HVVsHrObwKF4mY0M3Usi2pnLYohlQsY315ya@xHnqIQAjucgfp2AkYA6OQHbqREalErrYYN/4uMCx89Lhwdr8MVXMsRPQRXhHJhoo4GeiGaM4/@uWoxagf6kcV2n4f/nsz6dX46Y8103HehZ7R2Zgn7Kfzs7ek8P5OoQSyvB6a74B) Link is to verbose version of code. Works by approximating the line integral for a quadrant. The default precision is unfortunately only ~5 significant figures so the first four bytes are needed to increase the precision to ~7 significant figures. Further increases are possible for the same byte count but then it becomes too slow to demonstrate on TIO. Explanation:

```
≧×χφ
```

Increase the number of pieces \$ n \$ in which to divide the quadrant from \$ 1,000 \$ to \$ 10,000 \$. `≧×φφ` would increase it to \$ 1,000,000 \$ but that's too slow for TIO.

```
ＮθＮη
```

Input the ellipse's axes \$ a \$ and \$ b \$.

```
Ｉ×⁴Σ
```

After calculating the approximate arc length of each piece into which the quadrant was subdivided, take the sum, multiply by \$ 4 \$ for the whole ellipse and output the result.

```
ＥＥφＥ²∕⁺ιλφ
```

Create a list of pieces of the quadrant. In the ellipse equation \$ \left ( \frac x a \right ) ^ 2 + \left ( \frac y b \right ) ^ 2 = 1 \$ we can set \$ \left ( \frac {x_i} a \right ) ^ 2 = \frac i n \$ and \$ \left ( \frac {y_i} b \right ) ^ 2 = 1 - \frac i n \$. Given a piece index \$ i \$ we want to calculate the distance between \$ ( x_i, y_i ) \$ and \$ ( x _{i+1}, y_{i+1} ) \$. For each \$ i \$ we calculate \$ j = \frac i n \$ and \$ k = \frac {i+1} n \$ and loop over the list.

```
₂⁺××θθ⁻Σι⊗₂Πι××ηη⁻⁻²Σι⊗₂⁻⊕ΠιΣι
```

The distance \$ \sqrt { ( a \sqrt k - a \sqrt j ) ^ 2 + ( b \sqrt { 1 - j } - b \sqrt { 1 - k } ) ^ 2 } \$ expands to  \$ 
\sqrt { a^2 \left ( j + k - 2 \sqrt { j k } \right ) + b^2 \left ( (1 - j) + (1 - k) - 2 \sqrt { (1 - j) (1 - k) } \right ) } \$ which expands to \$ 
\sqrt { a^2 \left ( j + k - 2 \sqrt { j k } \right ) + b^2 \left ( 2 - (j + k) - 2 \sqrt { 1 + j k - (j + k) } \right ) } \$.

Answer (score 1):

## [Symja](https://symjaweb.appspot.com/), 35 bytes

```
f=N(4*#1*EllipticE(1-#2*#2/#1/#1))&
```

[Try It Online!](https://symjaweb.appspot.com/input?i=f%3dN%284%2a%231%2aEllipticE%281%2d%232%2a%232%2f%231%2f%231%29%29%26%3bf%2820%2c10%29)

A port of the SageMath answer in Symja.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 35 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
MP*ºH=3*(U-V ²/(U±V)/(A+(4-H/U ¬ +U
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=TVAqukg9MyooVS1WILIvKFWxVikvKEErKDQtSC9VIKwgK1U&input=MTIzCjQ1)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
I÷S²3×÷ạ4½+⁵Ʋ$‘×S×ØP
```

A monadic Link accepting a pair of `[a, b]` which yields the result of formula 5.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATYAyf9qZWxsef//ScO3U8KyM8OXw7fhuqE0wr0r4oG1xrIk4oCYw5dTw5fDmFD///9bMTIzLCA0NV0)**

---

I thought formula 4 would be the way to go, but only got 21:

```
9Ḷ.c×⁹I÷S*⁸¤²ʋ€×ØP×SS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATgAx/9qZWxsef//OeG4ti5jw5figblJw7dTKuKBuMKkwrLKi@KCrMOXw5hQw5dTU////1sxMjMsIDQ1XQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 40 bytes

```
A,hQeQJc^-GH2^+GH2**.n0+GHhc*3J+T@-4*3J2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/31EnIzA10Cs5TtfdwyhOG0hoaenlGQAZGclaxl7aIQ66JkDa6P//aEM9Ix3DWAA)

Just formula 5, like most other answers here.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 70 bytes

```perl
sub{my$s;map$s+=sqrt+($_[0]*cos)**2+($_[1]*sin)**2,0..1570795;4e-6*$s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZBNj9owEIbv/hUW9ZIQghN/JTEh6vZSqepWPbQ9LQiFykGR@KoddouW7V@nttnS5DCe9/HMO@MclN6Iy9Eo@NCabjr90bUbGJjjNigBaqqLOa5etidkym19QGZcmV@6G4do@Zguop97M4oi6iVZRKbdORmnGBORp7kUJVeTLELm9VICN@K7ciO@7LUqwfYE7zurK2v8aA6btlvE/kjmuySezQK7AIHuu8YM04KRQrA0BwTTHpdU5JIQKSwXN55jyWhOpF0D0J6PxFlRcF5QmgLW44RhlvHCNlEgepwSnJI05VxwQFPPfZQZvvkQ6py4bxMiwxkTUrLszR/68UTgIhOcSSEBaPY69K8fvQB3uT2FqI7RKkbq92FU3aNl@cbRet9VQ9Rc70c3rLSuXPHEFfTpUqtNVa9M6ETi/Ur4zsK6a58UtHCvfflBt7sO/muBM/euKIKTDL6HwdfPEAZwCoOPHz49BGWvYQDr6m7CDFxdjzqxicCsgXaURYQY6HZ2GXbCbXpnc@6H@/WclM1/yTFV890AXH9X9cck4fzbeFT5mBg/uBnYKzQcxOqp3iBii87z5/F5jtDwvNaxStZKg9fLXw)

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 78 bytes

```perl
sub f{($a,$b)=@_;$H=3*(($a-$b)/($a+=$b))**2;3.141593*$a*(1+$H/(10+sqrt 4-$H))}
```

With the `a+=b` trick stolen from the Javascript answer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZHbbtswDIbv9RRCqtaH2LJ1sq04xrqbIcM67GLbVRMEDiAHBnKa5bYrmuzVM0npMhsCRX4if9LgQXUbcX7SCj60up9MfvbtBnr6aeuVZ/20gs2bj@oIrYLqflmiWcVC34DYgMTc48o4QRjSkmHCiZAsRHXokzGaJT5Jx/pX10Meo1kQnM43Fz2u4iw0DeC2PqDlY7oIXRaJfXMMIIvEYSsbhLrdGWj9KMWYiDzNpTgBO/APZQf@uu9UCbav8L43cWVEH/Vh0/aLyF3JfJdE06nnlYBA@11shmnBSCFYmgOC6YBLKnJJiBSGiyvPsWQ0J9I0B3SgI3FWFJwXlKaADThhmGW8MEUUiAGnBKckTTkXHNDUcWdlhq86hFol7sqEyHDGhJQsA6DZd777y@AN2Mft62U3EVK/D2ZBaFm@c7Te91XzvrkrVF1X2dTYPg/pslObql5p3waJUyvhjYF13z4raOC@c@mHrt318F8JnNrpwxDGGfwAvW9fIPTgBHqfPn5@8MpBwQjW1W3MNFxdrjoxjsCsgaaVQYRoaCe2HraBnfTW@Nw1d@PZUDb/Q46pmu9GrguE1R@d@PPv46ByNtGucTMyT@huFKnneoOISTrOX8bHOUJ3x3UXqWStOnA6/wU)

Or this one which is 13 bytes less (but uses core module List::Util)

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) -MList::Util=sum, <s>74</s> <s>65</s> 65+16 bytes

```perl
sub f{4e-6*sum map sqrt+($_[0]*cos)**2+($_[1]*sin)**2,0..1570795}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZDLbtswEEX3/IqBq0S2LFPiSxItC003BYqm6KLtKjYMuaAMAX6VlJMGcfrrLkmnrrQYzj0zc4fUQemNOB@NgvvWdNPpj67dQGiO27A8m@MKmheuJllkAWzrA5hfuhsPg@VDuoh@7s0oiqiXZBGZdudknGJMRJ7mUrx63@/K@X7Za1Wi7TPcdVZX1uvBHDZtt4j9kcx3STybhWGJCLjvEjNMC0YKwdIcEUx7XFKRS0KksFxceY4lozmRdjmiPR@Js6LgvKA0RazHCcMs44Udokj0OCU4JWnKueCIpp77KDN89SHUOXE/JkSGMyakZNmbP/j1ROAiE5xJIRFq9nroXz96Qa64fR4GdRys4kD9Poyqu2BZvvFgve@q5lIdXaHSunKtE1fu06VWm6pemaETiXcr4Z2Fddc@KrBwr337Qbe7Dv6NwMy9KopgksF7CL9@BghhCuHHD5/uw7I3MIC6upkwA6vLUSc2EZg1YFdZRIgBd2OXYSfcTW9szv1yfz0nZfNfckzVfDdAl59V/THJcP5tPKp8TIxf3AxsKbgdxOqx3gTENp3mT@PTPAhuT2sdq2StNHo9/wU)

Which numerically calculates a variant of formula (1).

I was surprised this worked with sin and cos of integers up to 1570795 ≈ 500000π. But the tests in the question in "Try it online" has relative error < 0.000001. Guess `sin²(the integers)` is "averaged out" good enough.

Comment: Our [usual rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/188/39242) require you to include `use List::Util 'sum';` in the byte count, no? That said, `map sqrt(($_[0]*cos$_)**2+($_[1]*sin$_)**2)` saves 4 bytes.

Comment: Maybe? I swapped the first answer to my four byte longer answer. I thought that since List::Util has been a core module for many years (since 2002), all normal Perl installations have it. Seems a matter of "administration" for a language which functions are true built-ins and which are semi-built-in in core modules that doesnt require extra installations. I've seen C answers without `#include <math.h>` and Javascript answers regularly omits `f=` in function definitions.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Thx for the cos-sin-tip. And it can even loose five extra bytes with `map sqrt+($_[0]*cos)**2+($_[1]*sin)**2`. I get a warning about sqrt not having parens. Sin and cos uses $_ without args.

Comment: There’s no exemption for matters of “administration”. A C program can still run (with a warning) without `#include <math.h>`, and we [allow](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1501/39242) function expressions without `f=` (unless the function is [recursive](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10360/39242)). Your program does not run without `use List::Util 'sum';`. The issue is not whether it exists to be imported; the issue is that must be explicitly imported to be used even when it exists.

Comment: As for `-MList::Util=sum`, we [count the command line flag](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/273/39242) as +17 bytes.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg [The most recent consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/78410) is that we don't count command line flags at all, and it suffices to mention the flags used alongside the language name (which OP already did).

Comment: @Bubbler Ah okay, I retract the comment about `-MList::Util=sum`.

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 29 bytes

```
{_:+_P*@:-@d/_*3*_4\-mqA+/)*}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1fWPe/Ot5KOz5Ay8FK1yFFP17LWCveJEY3t9BRW19Tq/Z/3f9oUwXDWAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 31 bytes

```
f(a,b)=4*a*ellE((1-b^2/a^2)^.5)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboW-9M0EnWSNG1NtBK1UnNyXDU0DHWT4oz0E-OMNOP0TDUhqm4WJhYU5FRqJCro2ikUFGXmlQCZSiCOkkJyYk6ORpqOQqKmpo5CdLShjoJhLJBhqGcEZ5lCWTARYygNFzcAMgzAao2AciamsbFQi2HOBAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org)/[mpmath](https://mpmath.org), 51 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:8*elliprg(0,a*a,b*b)
from mpmath import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYxNCsIwEEb3PcUsM2EsxqqUojdxk6CxgfwRxoVncRMQvZO3UVI378EH73u8853nFOvTHk-vG9vV-Bm8DuasQZOZRnnx3uVyFWvS8rdIg50tKUDIQfMMLuRUWP7Tg00FGFwEIRQpJKH6XfOmcd-4pQFx6iAXF1kwgRWSEZePWhd_AQ)

Using Carlson's symmetric integrals – as seen [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/257775/110698) – not only removes the need to sort input, it saves 1 byte off the bog-standard \$4aE(e)\$ formula. As given in [DLMF 19.30.5](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.30#E5), \$L=8R_G(0,a^2,b^2)\$.

Comment: elliprg also exists in scipy I notice.

Answer (score 0):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [22 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

```
┴þ5‡Ôç¸„”R¤ËíÜç›WðÙÝÁ*
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=cGkqKDMqKCtcKS06LygqMys6fSkqKzMqOn0=&input=WzEgMV0KWzEuMiAxXQpbMiAxXQpbMjAgMTBd&flags=ZQ==) A pretty good approximation, but not exact for the larger values. Uses the crossed out formula (which I assume was removed due to the innacuracy). For any wondering, I managed to get the non-crossed out formula 5 to 33 bytes, but I couldn't figure out how to shorten it (and it was even less accurate than this one).

## Explained

Unpacked: `pi*(3*(+\)-:/(*3+:})*+3*:}`

```
pi                     Variable; first 20 digits of π
  *
    (
          3
        *
          (+\)         Folded sum ([a, b] -> a + b)
      -
        :/             Square root
            (
                  _    Variable; initialized to STDIN; implied
                *
                  3
              +
                  _    Implied
                :}     Tail
            )
          *
              _        Implied
            +
                3
              *
                  _    Implied
                :}
                       Ending parentheses implied
```