# How spherical is my ellipsoid?

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry, 3d

Define the (unnormalised) [Willmore energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willmore_energy) of a surface as the integral of squared mean curvature over it:
$$W=\int_SH^2\,dA$$
For surfaces topologically equivalent to a sphere \$W\ge4\pi\$, and \$W=4\pi\$ iff it is actually a sphere. Thus the energy quantifies how spherical a surface is.

In September 2020 [I asked on MathsSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3822237/357390) how to simplify the Willmore energy of an ellipsoid with semi-major axes \$a\ge b\ge c\ge0\$. Two days later I had done it myself:

> Define
> $$A=a^2,B=b^2,C=c^2,\varphi=\cos^{-1}\frac ca$$
> $$g=\sqrt{(A-C)B},m=\frac{(B-C)A}{(A-C)B}$$
> Then
> $$\color{red}{\begin{align}W=\frac\pi{3ABC}&\Big(C(5AB+2AC+2BC)\\
> &+2(AB+AC+BC)E(\varphi,m)g\\
> &+BC(AB+AC+2BC-A^2)F(\varphi,m)/g\Big)\end{align}}$$

Here \$F\$ and \$E\$ are the [elliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) of the first and second kinds respectively. (Note that as with all my elliptic integral/function answers on MathsSE the argument convention is as in Mathematica and mpmath, where \$m\$ is the *parameter*.) Later on I derived a much cleaner and order-agnostic formula in terms of [Carlson's symmetric integrals](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.16) – \$A,B,C\$ keep their meanings:
$$W=\frac\pi3\left(3+4\left(\frac1A+\frac1B+\frac1C\right)R_G(AB,CA,BC)-(A+B+C)R_F(AB,CA,BC)\right)$$
I was inspired to write this question after writing answers to the [ellipse perimeter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/257777/110698) and [ellipsoid surface area](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/257775/110698) questions that use the symmetric integrals. In the former case it actually saves one byte over an answer using the classic formula.

### Task

Given an ellipsoid's semi-axes \$a,b,c\$, which you may assume are sorted and positive, output the ellipsoid's Willmore energy with a relative error of at most \$10^{-3}\$. You may use either formula above or something else entirely like explicitly integrating the squared mean curvature.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf); fewest bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
(1, 1, 1) 12.5663706143592
(2, 1, 1) 15.4516066443266
(2, 2, 1) 16.9023119660317
(3, 2, 1) 21.2244261324396
(2, 2, 2) 12.5663706143592
(6, 1, 1) 34.2162831541838
(6, 5, 1) 70.4793621781325
(13, 9, 6) 15.9643343585267
```

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES6), 195 bytes

Quite obviously not the right tool for the job, at least without any specialized library. The only math builtins used here are \$\sin\$, \$\cos\$ and \$\operatorname{hypot}\$.

The precision can be improved by using a smaller increment (the \$i\$ in the code). The version below uses \$i=10^{-2}\$ so that it doesn't time-out on TIO. But as a result, the relative error is \$\approx10^{-1}\$.

```javascript
with(Math)f=(a,b,c)=>{i=1e-2;for(F=G=p=0;S=sin(p+=i),P=S*i*i/12,p<PI;)for(q=0;q<2*PI;G+=P*Q)F+=P/(Q=hypot(a*b*S*cos(q+=i),c*a*S*sin(q),b*c*cos(p)));return(4/a/a+4/b/b+4/c/c)*G-(a*a+b*b+c*c)*F+PI}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYzdSsQwEEbvfZLMJDU2uxakO3vZshdClz5BElubZWnSHxURn72meydWBmb4zhy@i37Xkx1dmJPevzTL8uHmjj3ruYOWmBZGWKDjl6O0SVTe@pEVVFKgh7ymyfUscHIgKqrRoZOpEuFQnXJYxSFKw0FhzCWnCs9QxCPZmbrP4Gem0WCN1k9suJVY1DGvpQMIg/b2CgCQj838NvZsL7XUfC@NNHFbaQHLJNZobtDw6AMWvDp9L9b3k78291f/ylqWijgAd7@p@oeqDbrbpKur/tBsszcTjxs03YknkQEsPw)

#### Formulas

This is derived from the second formula given in the challenge and the following formulas [from this page](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.23#E6_5) for Carlson's symmetric integrals:

$$R_F(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin\theta\:d\theta\:d\phi}{(x\sin^2\theta\cos^2\phi+y\sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi+z\cos^2\theta)^{1/2}}$$
$$R_G(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}(x\sin^2\theta\cos^2\phi+y\sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi+z\cos^2\theta)^{1/2}\sin\theta\:d\theta\:d\phi$$

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 63 bytes

-1 byte and fixed a bug thanks to [@att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/att).

```
Pi/3(3.-Tr[s=#^2]CarlsonRF@@(t=##&@@s/s)+4Tr[1/s]CarlsonRG@@t)&
```

`CarlsonRG` and `CarlsonRF` are new functions in Mathematica 12.3, so this does not work on TIO.

Comment: `1##&@@#/#`->`##&@@#/#`

Comment: I think you need to square the argument (since \$A=a^2\$ etc.)